# Json Reply contains Error in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

**HTML Button and textbox**

```
<input id="txt_bx_tagline" type="text"/>
<input id="btn_savelogo" type="button" value="Save"/>
```

**Ajax method Output is alert("Error")**

```
<script>
$("#btn_savelogo").click(function () {
    var vartxtbx_tagline = $('#txt_bx_tagline').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "settings.aspx/Insertlogo",
            data: "{'tagline':'" + vartxtbx_tagline.toString() + "'}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {

                alert("Success"); 

            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("Error");

            }
        });       

});`</script>`
```

**Code behind Of settings.aspx.**
**Is this WebMethod Must static ?**

```
[WebMethod]
    public string Insertlogo(string tagline)
    {
        objbal.insertlogo("abc.jpg", tagline); // bal class method
        retun "true";
    }
```

Comment: Its not necessary for webmethod to be static. Does your browser console have any errors? If yes, can you paste it here?

Comment: POST http://localhost:1979/Admin/settings.aspx/Insertlogo net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 
POST http://localhost:1979/Admin/settings.aspx/Insertlogo net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Comment: What value is passed to `tagline`? Is the value too big?

Comment: Nope its just simple text i am passing like "abc" max to max 20 characters

Comment: I tested your code in my project. It works perfect. Passing simple text should not be any problem either. Check if you've antivirus that's blocking the request. Disable it if you have antivirus. Also, try to check it from next browser.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
[WebMethod]
    public static string Insertlogo(string tagline)
    {
        objbal.insertlogo("abc.jpg", tagline); // bal class method
        retun "true";
    }

Answer (score 0):

Make the function static

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string Insertlogo(string tagline)
    {
       objbal.insertlogo("abc.jpg", tagline); // bal class method
        retun "true";
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

WebMethod "Insertlogo" doesn't have to be static. You can make it static only if the field you used "objbal" is static.

Verify the url you gave. If it is MVC application default url pattern will be {Controller}/{ActionMethod}/{Params}

In general you can make any Method static if you can say YES to below points.

1. Your methods is independent of non static fields and properties in that class.
2. You want to access the method with out creating an instance to the class